# Google Piechart

Tags: pie-chart, google-pie-chart

i try to create a pie chart on my Website, i found the example code

```
<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load google charts
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Draw the chart and set the chart values
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work', 8],
            ['Eat', 2],
            ['TV', 4],
            ['Gym', 2],
            ['Sleep', 8]
        ]);

        // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
        var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':550, 'height':400};

        // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_pie_chart)

But i only get a Error Message :

> Table has no columns.

Can someone help me pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunatelly I cannot comment.

This code works - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atpm2bnu/). Could you give more details about this project?

sample of code for fiddle

```
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

edit:

> Table has no columns.

Is this error message from browser console?

Comment: I use it in smarty in a .tpl file for a shopsystem.